# PHP Autoloading classes not found

Tags: php, autoload

I have folder structure like:

```
includes/
    class-autoload.inc.php

config/
    classes/
       admin.class.php
    
admin/
    clients.php
```

**admin.class.php** is my class that file that I'm trying to use. The file contains.

```
<?php


class Admin extends Dbh{
     .
     .
     .
```

I have my **class-autoload.inc.php** file like:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');

function myAutoLoader ($className){
        $path = 'config/classes/';
        $extension = '.class.php';
        $fileName = $path . $className . $extension;

        if(!file_exists($fileName)){
            return false;
        }

        include_once $path . $className . $extension;


}
```

The file I'm trying to use the admin class in is **clients.php** within the **admin/** folder. My clients.php file is like:

```
<?php
include '../includes/class-autoload.inc.php' ;

$admin = new Admin();
```

and i have this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Admin' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are not resolved based on the location of the current file, but based on the "working directory" at run-time.

To specify a path relative to the current file, use the [magic constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) `__DIR__`, e.g.

```php
include __DIR__ . '/../includes/class-autoload.inc.php';
```

and

```php
include_once __DIR__ . '/../' . $path . $className . $extension;
```

As an additional tip, if you use [`require`](https://php.net/require) instead of `include`, you'll get an error if the file is not found, rather than it silently failing.